# Is it possible to remote forward tcp through a free proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy

I’m aware you can forward connection from a proxy server like this:

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 public.example.com
```

But I’m curious if it’s possible to forward from a free proxy such as:

```
https://free-proxy-list.net
```

Seems unlikely to use the ssh option because I wouldn’t have access to the server. If so what would be a practical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a remote HTTP proxy, SSH is not the tool for the job. SSH -D can open a local port to act as a SOCKSv4 or SOCKSv5 proxy, but this requires you to connect to a remote SSH server, not an open HTTP server. SSH -R or SSH -L also require the endpoint to offer SSH authentication so they won't work as plain HTTP proxies.

Proxychains is likely what you're after, or just configuring the browser to use the proxy (Firefox offers this for sure, not sure about other browsers).

SoCat or NetCat would work as 'dumb' proxys as they are effectively just tools for handling TCP connections and don't require authentication, but you may have to experiment with them through an HTTP proxy. Again, not likely the right tool for this.

@domen thanks for correcting me. Clearly wasn't thinking straight when I wrote the first version ;)

Comment: `ssh -D` will make ssh *act* as a SOCKS proxy, not connect through it.